How can I sender mail with custom sender field?
My mail is not passing SPF checks when delivering to gmail. My error message reads:
Your email has been blocked because the sender is unauthenticated. Gmail requires all senders to authenticate with either SPF or DKIM. Authentication results: DKIM = did not pass SPF [localhost.localdomain] with ip: [ip.address] = did not pass

I previously had SPF correctly configured, including my DNS settings. I have recently reconfigured my local postfix, so I believe the issue to be my local configuration. I suspect it is due to the error section did not pass SPF [localhost.localdomain].
When I check the returned mail sender address, it displays user@localhost.localdomain - which will fail SPF as it is not my domain name.
I believe I could solve this issue by adding:
mydomain = mydomain.com

to postfix. My question is, how do I set the sender address to be custom, each time I send mail ? This is because I have multiple users and multiple domains on my machine.
For example, I would like to be able to have mail appear to originate from:

user1@domain1
user2@domain1
user1@differentdomain1
How could this be achieved with postfix ?

My OS is Ubuntu. I am after solutions that rely only on Postfix - not other software. For example, I am not after a solution using Dovecot.
Ideally, I am after a solution where I could set custom address's while being signed in as any system user (or at the very least, root). If this is not possible, a per user solution would also be helpful.
